# Why does compressing this PDF using "convert" make this pdf bigger?

Tags: pdf, convert

Using the command `convert -density 100 -quality 100 in.pdf out.pdf` to convert a scan into a smaller pdf has worked for me before. Yet I have come accross a scan that it does not work on.

I have tried various command combinations like `-density 50% -quality 50%` or `-resize 50%` together with `-compress jpg`, which by the way gives me the following error while performing its task:

```
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `jpg': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
convert-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/560.
```

meaning it did not find the "jpg" file or folder?
So far every compression attempt reduced the quality while increasing the file size. Maybe the scan uses some kind of compression that convert does not use?

Comment: Sometimes compression on an object will increase file size if that compression algorithm is not suited for the file you are giving it.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt for this file even if i skip the "compress" option just resize 50% causes the file size to increase by almost double.

Comment: PDFs in general use internal compression for the objects they contain. So when you start compressing a compressed file the result can add characters making it bigger

Comment: If the original PDF is primarily text, then it might be stored more efficiently as a text document.  Changing that to an image could increase its size.  As a trivial example, the letter "A" in a `.txt` file occupies one byte.  Open it on your computer and take a photo of it, and it most certainly will be larger than one byte...  As others have said, compression can make files bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just exported that pdf using libreoffice draw, 70% resize and it reduced the filesize by more than half!
I am super confused why, but it works so i am happy.